# Angular material tab not working properly

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to implement angular material tabs in my angular app.
Angular are behaving abruptly in my code. On clicking they changes their position and then comes back to same position again To check my code, please use this link - https://stackblitz.com/github/vibhorgoyal18/atest-blog

The route for the page on which these tabs are implemented are - /login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<mat-tab-group>
..
</mat-tab-group>
```

to

```
<mat-tab-group disableRipple>
..
</mat-tab-group>
```

read more about ripples [here](https://material.angular.io/components/ripple/overview)